# Advanced Voice Command (From A Distance)

Tags: windows, software-rec, voice-command

I've just bought a new wireless headset and found out, to my surprise, the signal is perfect even from upstairs in my bedroom.  I figure, it has several hours of battery life, why not utilize it for something good!

**My Question**

Most voice command software seems to be focused on the fact that you are still sitting right in front of the computer, is there any voice command software designed for those who can't see their computer?  Perhaps even software meant for the blind?  The more features the better.  I'm just curious on what is out there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 has built in voice recognition, useful mainly for dictation.  [There are some commands available](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Common-commands-in-Speech-Recognition), such as open a program, minimize a window, etc.

But this begs the question - what kinds of things do you want to tell your computer to do when you can't see the screen?

There is also a new Windows program called [Mitini](http://www.redmondpie.com/mitini-is-siri-for-windows-7-with-natural-voice-dictation-download-now-video/) ([download](http://code.google.com/p/serk/downloads/detail?name=Mitini.exe&can=2&q=)) which is similar to Siri on the iPhone - does a lot of cool stuff.  Using this with your wireless headset would be like having an assistant in your head!

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea, but you may try turning on some accessibility features (text to speech?) and see if that adds to your "away from the screen" experience when using the headset.

Comment: the "narrator" does that. it is a terrible implementation.  trying to use it made me understand  the difficulty a blind user might have.